# $N$ independent spins, mean value of $m_N$

Tags: statistical-mechanics

We have $N$ independent spins $s_i$ which can take on values $-1$ and $1$ with probabilities $p(s_i=1)=p$, $p(s_i=-1)=q$. For the total magnetization $M$ we can get N+1 different values $-N,-N+2,...,N-2,N$. I realize, that the mean of $m_N$ (magnetization per volume) can be expressed as
\begin{align}
 \langle m_N \rangle & = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N} m_i p(m_i) \\
 & = \sum_{i=0}^{N} \begin{pmatrix} N \\ i \end{pmatrix} (2 \underbrace{\frac{i}{N}}_{\equiv n_i} - 1 )\ q^{N-i} \ p^{i}
\end{align}
but how is this equivalent to this other approach:
\begin{align}
 \langle m_N \rangle & = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N} \langle s_i \rangle \\
 & = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N} \left[p\cdot 1 + q \cdot (-1)\right]\\
 & = 2p-1
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is equivalent to the proof that the expectation value of the Binomial distribution for $N$ trials with success probability $p$ is $Np$, and it can be found in the corresponding section of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Expectation). I won't reproduce the whole of the proof here, but the starting point is
$$
\mu = \sum_{k=0}^N k \binom{N}{k} p^k q^{N-k}
$$
Because the term with $k=0$ vanishes, it is possible to replace the lower limit of the sum by $k=1$.
A factor $Np$ is pulled out to the front of the sum, and the summand is re-written in terms of $\ell=k-1$ and $M=N-1$; the factor $k$ gets absorbed into the binomial coefficient, i.e. the $k!$ term in the denominator becomes $\ell!$; the $(N-k)!$ term is already equal to $(M-\ell)!$. The result is
$$
\mu = Np \, \sum_{\ell=0}^M \binom{M}{\ell} p^\ell q^{M-\ell}
$$
Because of the binomial theorem, and the fact that $p+q=1$, the sum in this equation is $1$, so you get the result $\mu=Np$. On that page, they also mention that it can be proved by adding up the $N$ independent variable expectation values of $p$.

In your case $k$ represents the number of up spins, and you are interested in the net magnetization $2k-N$, divided by $N$. But the steps in the proof are the same.

Comment: thank you! with that trick i came to the same result as with the other way, $2p-1$.